# Can Eclipse MAT's ParseHeapDump utility run OQL?

Tags: java, heap-dump, oql, eclipse-mat

Typically I use Eclipse MAT GUI to run [OQL](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Ftasks%2Fqueryingheapobjects.html) on a heap dump to extract data. I was just wondering if there is any way to run any OQL with ParseHeapDump utility? Basically, I wanted to go beyond [those four standard reports](https://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#How_to_run_on_64bit_VM_while_the_native_SWT_are_32bit) and run my own OQLs to find out cause.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own report which could then execute the OQL.
The report is a small XML file.
See [MAT forum post: Command Line processing of hprof](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1068073/?srch=oql%20report#msg_1068073)

I think you could also pass in the actual OQL command from your command line using ${} substitution in the report XML, but you would need to be careful about substitution and escaping of quotes etc.

Eclipse Memory Analyzer 1.11 will have the `org.eclipse.mat.api:query` to run a single query in a report. Unfortunately the command line escaping of backslash and double-quote makes the syntax look complicated, but there is help.